# How to do a remote post from controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, payment-gateway

I've got a checkout page that is supposed to redirect user to the payment-gateway payment processing page. It expects form data to be posted (Amount, Access_key, Order_id, etc;).

What I've gotten so far is this;

```
public class OrderController : Controller {
  private readonly IOrderService _service;

  public OrderController(IOrderService service) {
    _service = service;
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index () {
    // order processing form
    // order model binding code not included for brevity.
    return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessOrder (OrderModel model) {
    var orderId = _service.CreateOrder(model);
    // order processing code not included for brevity. (basically create new order and reduce stock)

    var dataToPost = new PGData() {
      Amount = 10,
      Currency = USD,
      TxId = orderId,
      SuccessUrl = "https://test@domain.com/order/success",
      FailedUrl = "https://test@domain.com/order/fail"
      Access_Key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      Field_Hash = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    };

    // need to redirect user to ("https://pg@pgdomain.com/paynow") with the post data above
  }

}
```

I've found a code snippet that works with .Net Framework but not with .Net Core:

```
private class RemotePost
{
  private NameValueCollection Content = new NameValueCollection();

  public string Url = "";
  public string Method = "post";
  public string FormName = "form1";

  public void Add(string name, string value)
  {
    Content.Add(name, value);
  }

  public void Post()
  {
    HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">", FormName));
    
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >", FormName, Method, Url));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Inputs.Keys.Count; i++)
    {
      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", Inputs.Keys[i], Inputs[Inputs.Keys[i]]));
    }
    
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
  }
}
```

How do I go about achieving this in .Net Core (3.1) in the most secure way as possible?

Answer (score 0):

The `ProcessOrder` method creates the remote object for external destination (your `dataToPost`) and returns a view:

```
return View(dataToPost);
```

The `ProcessOrder.cshtml` view accepts a `PGData` model:

```
@model PGData
```

This view contains a form with hidden inputs for each property that needs to be sent to the external destination:

```
<form name="my-form" method="POST" action="https://pg@pgdomain.com/paynow">
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Amount"/>
  ...
</form>
```

A piece of JavaScript code will submit this form on document load:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.forms['my-form'].submit();
}
```

Usually the payment gateways call a callback endpoint in your website and you can check the status of payment and if the data was tampered with.

By the way you need to read the documentation of your gateway endpoint carefully since you're dealing with money here. They usually provide example code for popular web frameworks.